# Timeout for all the test cases in pytest

Tags: pytest

I have the requirement to stop test cases with overall timeout, not at test case level.
so if lets say i have 300 test cases I want to timeout with overall time as 300 seconds.

Is there a way to do that?
Sample command used to run pytest 
pytest.py  --junitxml=artifacts/junitresults.xml -s --gatherlogs=true --durations=2000 tests/spark

Answer (score 6):

take a look at this pytest plugin: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-timeout it most probably suits your use case.

You can set a global timeout in a number of ways, the most simple one being the `--timeout` command line option that "sets a global timeout overriding both the environment variable and configuration option" after which the tests will be terminated:

```
py.test --timeout=300
```

Comment: Using this I can have timeout at test case level but I want to have timeout for all the test cases. Is it possible to have overall timeout?

Comment: Yes you can, as pointed in the PyPi description you can specify a command line argument to do so. I updated the answer to clarify this point.

Comment: it's setting a timeout for each test, not a limit on the duration of the whole test run. See README `pytest --timeout=300` "any individual test which takes longer than the given duration will be terminated"